# Pass custom API key in command line with Cypress

Tags: javascript, api, testing, cypress, api-key

I am testing with Cypress, connecting to an external API that requires a key, however I am conscious about not pushing a private key publicly on GitHub.

Is there a way in which I can pass my API key through the command line or in another safe way at the time of running the Cypress app?

```
"run-cypress": "cypress run --browser chrome --reporter-options configFile=cypress.json"
```

Could I append something such as

```
apiKey=abcdefg...
```

after `configFile...`? And how would I access this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it alongside some CI tool (e.g. TravisCI or CircleCI), you can **save your API key as the environment variable in your CI dashboard.** Then during the CI build, key is read from your settings and therefore never needs to be pushed to source control.

I was in the very same situation as you couple of weeks ago. Here's my [Pull Request](https://github.com/boxwise/boxwise/pull/478) where I've removed the key (and then manually put it to our CI settings instead)